# lapply and apply for each component and element of a list R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have this list:

```
lst

lst <- list(a=c(2.5,9.8,5.0,6.7,6.5,5.2,34.4, 4.2,39.5, 1.3,0.0,0.0,4.1,0.0,0.0,25.5,196.5, 0.0,104.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),b=c(147.4,122.9,110.2,142.3))
```

I would like to calculate for each values of a list and for each element of a list (`a` and `b`) a z.score as:  `(x[i]-mean(x)/sd(x)`, where x are all values (togheter) of each element of a list and x[i] each single component of each list element. 
I tried with `lapply`

```
lapply(lst,function (x) as.data.frame(apply(x,2, function(y)- lapply(lst,mean)/lapply(lst,sd))))
```

but there is an error...
maybe with `for` loop as:

```
lst.new <- vector("list",1)

for (i in 1:length(lst)){
  for (j in 1:dim(data.frame(lst[i]))[1]){
    res[j] <- (as.numeric(unlist(lst[i]))[j]-mean(as.numeric(unlist(lst[i])))/
      sd(as.numeric(unlist(lst[i])))
    lst.new[[i]] <- res
  }
}
```

but the result is strange (sure I'm wrong in the `lst.new` output):

```
[[1]]
 [1] -0.3635464 -0.1982809 -0.3069486 -0.2684621 -0.2729899 -0.3024208  0.3586413 -0.3250599  0.4741007 -0.3907133
[11] -0.4201442 -0.4201442 -0.3273238 -0.4201442 -0.4201442  0.1571532  4.0284412 -0.4201442  1.9388512 -0.4201442
[21] -0.4201442 -0.4201442 -0.4201442 -0.4201442

[[2]]
 [1]  0.9671130 -0.4517055 -1.1871746  0.6717671 -0.2729899 -0.3024208  0.3586413 -0.3250599  0.4741007 -0.3907133
[11] -0.4201442 -0.4201442 -0.3273238 -0.4201442 -0.4201442  0.1571532  4.0284412 -0.4201442  1.9388512 -0.4201442
[21] -0.4201442 -0.4201442 -0.4201442 -0.4201442
```

the expected result can be a list or a data frame with different length as:

```
 a       b
   -0.36    0.967113
  -0.19     -0.45
    [...]  [...]
```

and so on...

```
P.S: 
 0.36 == (2.5- mean(unlist(lst[1])))/sd(unlist(lst[1]))
 0.967113 == (147.4 -mean(unlist(lst[2])))/sd(unlist(lst[2]))
```

It's better for me to use `lapply` (or his family function) and to resolve the problem

Comment: Did you meant `lapply(lst, scale)`

Comment: A couple side notes:  (a) `apply` is for matrices. You don't have matrices, so you don't need `apply` inside your `lapply`. (b) Use `[[` to access a single list item. Basically whenever you have something like `unlist(lst[2])` you should use `lst[[2]]`.

Comment: ok 'scale' works.... but if I want to apply a my personal function (e.g x[i]*10000/mean(x)), different respect scale, how can apply it to each values and element of a list? Using 'lapply(lapply...)'? Thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness' sake, if there wasn't the `scale` function @akrun pointed out, your code should have been:

```
lapply(lst,function(x) x-mean(x)/sd(x))
```

all those `lapply`s within `apply`s mean you're trying to calculate the `mean` and `sd` of individual values...

Let's work through it step by step.
`lapply` takes `lst` and breaks it down into elements. Each element in turn is given as the argument to your anonymous function. That means the function gets a vector of numbers. Then, using R's vectorization, what we do is calculate for every element of the vector the result of that element, minus the `mean` of the whole vector divided by the `sd` of the whole vector.

Compare that with what happens in your code:

```
lapply(lst,function (x) as.data.frame(apply(x,2, function(y)- lapply(lst,mean)/lapply(lst,sd))))
```

So the first `lapply` breaks lst and sends the vectors one at a time to your function.

The function then has to break the vector down by columns (`apply` with dimension argument 2) - which is where it throws the error. But even if it succeeded to just break down the vector into elements, you then have two more `lapply`s that break down that single element and calculate the `mean` and `sd` for them individually.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the input and the expected output, `scale` should work

```
lapply(lst, scale)
```